# AngularJs - Adding new property to item gives dulpcate values using .indexOf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof

I am using the following to check for duplicate values in an array before I add a value:

```
vm.onGridItemChanged = function (resource) {

     if (vm.modifiedItems.indexOf(resource) === -1) {
        vm.modifiedItems.push(resource);
     } 
};
```

This works great and gives me behaviour I want. However I now have need to add EnglishValue also, so I have changed to:

```
vm.onGridItemChanged = function (resource, englishText) {

        var modifiedItem = {Resource: resource, EnglishValue: englishText};

        if (vm.modifiedItems.indexOf(modifiedItem) === -1) {
            vm.modifiedItems.push(modifiedItem);
        } 

    };
```

However this breaks the functionality and I am now getting duplicate values? Why would this be the case?

**Edit** - my josn includes `$$hashKey` values that is still causing duplicate issues:

```
[
  {
    "Resource": {
      "ResourceId": "Account_AccountVerified_Success_Title",
      "LocaleId": "de",
      "ResourceSet": "/WebResources",
      "Value": "Erfolg55",
      "Comment": "Success",
      "Editing": false,
      "$$hashKey": "object:3861"
    },
    "EnglishValue": "Success",
    "$$hashKey": "object:40483"
  },
  {
    "Resource": {
      "ResourceId": "Account_AccountVerified_Success_Title",
      "LocaleId": "de",
      "ResourceSet": "/WebResources",
      "Value": "Erfolg55",
      "Comment": "Success",
      "Editing": false,
      "$$hashKey": "object:3861"
    },
    "EnglishValue": "Success",
    "$$hashKey": "object:40488"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the JSON object to string and check its index. Since, you have `$$hashkey` in your object, you first need to remove that by `angular.toJson`

```
vm.onGridItemChanged = function (resource, englishText) {

        var modifiedItem = {Resource: resource, EnglishValue: englishText};
        var modifiedItems = angular.toJson(vm.modifiedItems);
        if (JSON.stringify(modifiedItems).indexOf(JSON.stringify(modifiedItem)) === -1) {
            vm.modifiedItems.push(modifiedItem);
        } 

    };
```

```js
var a = [{'d':'dasdasd','e':'dasdasda'}, {'d':'dasdasd','e':'dada'}];
var b =  {'d':'dasdasd','e':'dasdasda'};

var index = JSON.stringify(a).indexOf(JSON.stringify(b));

console.log(index);
```

See that we get the index of the JSON object that exist in the string. Likewise, index will be `-1` if not present on the JSON array.

Comment: Hi, sorry not working wit my data - see updated question.

Comment: I used `if (angular.toJson(vm.modifiedItems).indexOf(angular.toJson(modifiedItem)) === -1)` and working :)

Comment: Sure you can do that to minimize that one line. Please accept and upvote the answer for acceptance